# Accessing application data

Tags: java

I am using static fields to store application data, is that the standard way or is there any other way to do?

In Detail : First i want to read the settings from a DB and then store it in variables and use it through out the application in all the classes. right now I am using static fields so is this the standard way

Comment: you can create classes specifically for the data...

Comment: What kind of application data are you refering to? Configuration and Properties? Measurement data? Communication between classes?

Answer (score 0):

static fields are used to store class level information not object level. So if u need to sote a value which would be on class level then use static varialbe else use instance variable.

Comment: It might be better understood if you mention that static attributes will be common to all class instances as opposed to instance attributes which are unique to each class instance.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to store configuration/properties, you could create your own class for that or use one of the existing ones (for instance [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)). Those existing classes often offer the possibility to save the information to a file to later load them up again, which might be helpful.